# Projective space, immersion, embeding

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

How can I check if the map $F:\Bbb{P}^2\to \Bbb{P}^5$, given as follows $F([x,y,z])=([x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,yz,zx])$, is smooth, an immersion or an embedding?

Comment: What does it mean to be smooth? Write this down and the answer will be clear. Same with the other two.

Comment: I don't know how this calculation will be different from the one as If I had $F:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^6$ instead of projective spaces.

Comment: It is different in that you have to look at $F$ through charts to show that it smooth, and that there are chart where $F$ won't coincide with $F : (x,y,z) \mapsto =(x^2,y^2,z^2,xy,yz,zx)$. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbf{P}^n$ has $n+1$ open affine charts $\{x_i\not=0\}$ where I note $[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ the coordinates on $\mathbf{P}^n$, so that you have to look $F$ through $3$ charts $\varphi_i : U_i \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3$ at the source and $6$ charts $\psi_j : V_j \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^6$ at the target, that will give you $3\times 6 = 18$ "chart representations" $\psi_j\circ F \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$ of $F$ which will be smooth diffeomorphisms on their open set of definition (as you will check) which will show to you that $F$ is smooth. Looking at the $\psi_j\circ F \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$'s instead of looking at $F$ is called "looking $F$ through charts (at the source and the target)."

Comment: Ok. I understand the idea, more or less. I have still a few questions cause I'm still not sure how to use it in practise. Is $U_i$ a subset of $\Bbb{P}^2$ and $V_j$ a subset of $\Bbb{P}^5$? And shouldn't it be $\psi_j\circ F \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$ instead of $\varphi_i^{-1} \circ F \circ \psi_j$?

Comment: It should, corrected. About the charts, for the simpler $\mathbf{P}^1$ case, consider $U_0$, you have two charts $\varphi_0 ([x,y]) = y/x$ and $\varphi_1 ([x,y]) = x/y$ respectivly defined on $U_0$ and $U_1$ with values in $\mathbf{R}$, and with inverses $\varphi_0^{-1} (t) = [1,t]$ and$\varphi_1^{-1} (t) = [t,1]$. For $\mathbf{P}^2$ for instance $\varphi_0 ([x,y,z]) = (y/x,z/x)$ has inverse $\varphi_0^{-1} (u,v)= [1,u,v]$ etc etc. With explicit charts and inverse thereof, looking $F$ through charts should be easier. ;-)